# How to achieve the strange vocal effect on this track?

Tags: sound-design, effects, vocals

Here's a link to Jai Wolf- Indian Summer

How is this vocal effect achieved? I'm relatively new to production so go easy on me.

Not looking for anything exact, just a general idea of how I could do something similair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a pitched & chopped vocal track.

The idea is as follows , first take the vocal track and either pitch it up or speed it up.(If you speed it up it also gets pitched up , but if your track is slow , you can use an algorithmic pitch to pitch up the voice and keep the bpm)

Now you take chops of the vocal track and assign them to some kind of sampler pad (or some midi pad controller) This of course can be done with mouse and editing but a sampler style 16 pads will give you more freedom.

So as the vocal rides the songs beat signature you chop each step you want to chop , meaning 1/4 or 1/8 or 1/16(which is somewhat not feasible) - or even something trickier , but let's keep it simple.

So for example if we had Britney Spears's beloved "Oops i did it again"
we would have to chop 1st/4th: "Oops" | 2nd/4th : "i" | 3rd/4th : "did it" 4th/4th : "again".

So if you played a 1 - 3 - 3 - 2 pads you'd get , Oops , did , did , i.

That's what makes the vocal chops.

This is somewhat a stupid & very plain sampling explanation without getting too deep.

You need to look over (Vocal) Pitching & Chopping/Sampling for more information :D

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks man! Didn't think it would be that simple :)

Comment: @Charlie yep! It's not too hard to wrap your head around it!